# Rails: Use render & partial helper. Random order display?

Tags: render, partial

I tried to use refactor my show.html.erb using:

```js
<%= render @question.answers %>
```

into
        _answer.html.erb

My understanding is that the partial here will be rendered once for EACH answer that is in the @question.answers collection.

As the render method iterates over the @question.answers collection, it assigns each answer to a local variable named the same as the partial, i.e. answer

However, I realized that every time when I refresh the page, the order of the content inside answer will be random. It is not listed in descending/ascending order, just like @question.answers.each |answer| does.

Any way to fix?

Answer (score 0):

I kinda of solve it temporarily by putting

```
    default_scope {
    order("created_at ASC")
  }
```

into my model.

Now when I refresh the page, the order of answer content will be the same order.